# Dynamics NAV 2013 allowed interval date defined by the license file

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision

I'm on a dynamics NAV 2013 training (self study) with a perpetual license. I use a suitable database for a particular business (with some specific functionnalities)

When i want to change "Due Date" in "Service Order module>Service Jobs" i obtain this error message :

***In The current Company the date you've entered is outside the allowed interval (this is determined by the filter '??11*|b??12*|??01*|??02*', which is defined by the license file).***

when i choose a date before 03/01/2016 (March) i got this error message :

***Service Job Due Date cannot be in the past***

I need your help to find how can i change this filter (in the license file) in order to change this field easily.

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Never heard of standard functionality that would read license file except wnen using Cronus demo company. If it is not standard then I can't help.

Comment: yes, this is definitely not a standard functionality. This code is probably using a custom license file (and not the NAV flf). Debug the code

Answer (score 0):

Just as comments from ***Mak Sim*** and ***azatoth*** **This isn't NAV standard**. This is custom code. Debug the code and you can see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This **is** standard behaviour; NAV is effectively in 'Demo-Mode' at this point.

It seems to happen either when the license on your NAV Server expires, or when you have installed a new license, but not restarted the service.

In either case, the resolution is to install a valid license from the NAV Development Environment, then restart the NAV service on the middle-tier server.